# How can I test that some prop is received in the child component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a parent and a child component. From the parent I am sending for example an array of strings.
How can I write a test with my child component, where I should expect a prop - the array of strings.
If it is not sent, the test should fail.

I tried:

```js
it("renders correctly", () => {
  const props = {
    data: [],
  };
  const tree = shallow(<MyChildCompo {...props}/>);
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

but it does not work

Comment: Why are you testing that React passes props to components? I don't really understand your question, you are passing the props there in the test.

Comment: If some props is not sended from parent to child, and that prop is needed in the child component, the component will fail showing the results

Comment: You can define [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) and mark them `isRequired` if they are required. Your unit tests should test your code, not React's code.

Comment: I am using Enzyme to test the components that are my requirements, I don't need to to only unit tests.

Comment: Is it wrong to test the react components on this way ?

Comment: A snapshot test? No, nothing wrong with that. Passing a prop and then asserting the component received the prop is a bit useless. Does this child component do some conditional rendering if no `data` prop is passed, or if it's empty? If so you could test the conditionally rendered output is what you expect.

Comment: to elaborate: we know React works, because the React team did their job quite well, so we don't need to test "whether props passing works": we can trust it does. What do you _actually_ need to test, in terms of how _your_ code behaves?

Comment: Looks like he wants to check the value passed within the props. Checkout below answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the props value like this.

```
it("renders correctly", () => {
  const props = {
    data: [],
  };
  const tree = shallow(<MyChildCompo {...props}/>);
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  expect(tree.instance().props.data.length).toBe(0);
});
```